# Is there a tool to move an open window from one user to another?

Tags: windows

Background: the app in question, SyncBackPro, wants to run just once.

At work, we are several admins. Now all of them are on vacation except me. They all remain logged into the servers. I have full admin privileges and would like to close the window of a particular software SyncBackPro my colleague has open.

Ideas:

- Move the window to my screen - how?
- Alternatively, I would also send a WM_CLOSE message to that software or
- log him out gracefully

Comment: Question about *issues specific to corporate IT support and networks* are [off topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Just log them out, or kill all the SyncBackPro processes.  Moving process between user spaces would be fighting the security ingrained in the operating system.